# Displaying an image at it's exact resolution despite scaling - UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Within my application, I hope to display images and video at their exact resolution despite UI scaling. So, if a user opens a 1920x1080 image I'd like for it to be displayed on a users screen using exactly 1920x1080 pixels of their display. Right now, this is how I'm doing it:

```
        var displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
       
        var scaleFactor = displayInfo.RawPixelsPerViewPixel;

        var scaledWidth = MediaWidth / scaleFactor;
        var scaledHeight = MediaHeight / scaleFactor;
```

RawPixelsPerViewPixel returns a value such as 1.25 if the scale factor is set to 125%. After I check to see if the users screen is large enough, I then use the scaled height and width to set the size of the window containing the image or video (with adjustments for margins and other application UI elements):

```
        var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        view.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = (scaledWidth), Height = ((scaledHeight) + 142) });
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish what I've described? Also, will this work with multiple monitors with different scale factors?

Does anyone know of any tools that would allow me to confirm that the displayed resolution is accurate?

Thanks!

Comment: could you explain display image's exact resolution despite scaling? Do you means is you want display all px of 1080p image in the 720p screen?

Comment: I mean if I had a display that is 1920x1080 with it's UI scale set to 125%, I'd like for a 1280x720 image to be displayed with it's width going across 1280 pixels of the display. As I understand it, if I set a windows width to 1280 px when UI scaling is set to 125%, the windows width will actually be taking up 1600 pixels of display space.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do it, derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/disable-scaling), you could turn off layout scale, but it only available for xbox device.